# Can I install xscreensaver on Ubuntu MATE 64-bit?

Tags: mate, xscreensaver

I rather like xscreensaver. It allows me configure its gltext module as a clock, which also displays a current date.

I wondered If I could install it onto Ubuntu MATE 64-bit without breaking anything in my system. When I tried to uninstall my default screensaver I got a message stating that `mate-desktop` would be removed as well.

Comment: please post the exact message.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I have found-out that the message threatening to remove the desktop could be safely ignored. "Xscreensaver" could be installed and used (at least in Xubuntu) with no problems while your desktop is going to remain intact. Just make sure to install all the add-ons to enable functionality you want.